# Wrong XML don't give parsing error when XSD is attached

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have to deserialize XML. I have an XSD to control available tags. When I make some mistake and XML contains irregular tag, XmlSerializer don't give error, it skips the irregular tag instead.

**How I would be able to force a runtime error?**

Here is a part of my class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/BXTestScript.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/BXTestScript.xsd", IsNullable=false)]

public partial class BXTestScript {

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ActivateMenu", typeof(BXTestScriptActivateMenu))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("BreakPoint", typeof(BXTestScriptBreakPoint))]
    ...     
    public static BXTestScript ReadXml(string path) {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(BXTestScript));
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
            BXTestScript ts = (BXTestScript)ser.Deserialize(sr);
        return ts;
    }
    ...
}
```

All the program working fine if XML is valid and contains elements from schema only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `XmlSchemaSet` - this Post contains detailed instructions:
[xmlserializer validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705430/xmlserializer-validation)